# ElasticSearch look through multiple fields as a fuzzy query

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

```
{
    "title" : "That Uselessly Amazing Title",
    "author" : "Someone you have never heard of",
    "url" : "http://www.theuselessweb.com",
    "summary" : "a collection of useless websites",
    "tag" : ["useless","maybe useful"]
}
```

Say I have a schema that looks like the one shown above. The user asks the application to show something "useless".

How do I write a query that will look through the title, summary, and tags for the word "useless" as a fuzzy search?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the docs [Fuzzy match Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/fuzzy-match-query.html)

```
GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "fields":  [ "summary", "title", "tag" ],
      "query":     "useless",
      "fuzziness": "AUTO"
    }
  }
}
```

This query works because it's using a `multi_match` query

> Fuzziness works only with the basic `match` and `multi_match` queries. It
>   doesn’t work with phrase matching, common terms, or `cross_fields`
>   matches.

Otherwise you'll have to [combine](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bool-query.html) several `fuzzy`queries inside a `bool` Query

Comment: ok, got it to work. When I try "use" instead of "useless", I get no results. Why's that? Is there any way to allow that too? partial strings?

Comment: That depends on the analyzers, token filters, etc, you use to index the entities and then the way you search them. Say you're using the standard analyzer (english), your Title will be tokenized first into "That", "Uselessly", "Amazing" and "Title" tokens, then each token will be analyzed independently. For the token "Uselessly" I think the standard english analyzer stores "useless" (lowercase). So when you search "use" you find no results. Try playing with other analyzers, maybe you want to add add your own token filters. I personally prefer to use the ones given by ElasticSearch.GL!

Comment: I guess you're gonna love the Edge NGram tokenizer mixed with the standard tokenizer. Remember, for token filters order does matter